# Не сохраняются данные в Redis

Tags: redis

Использую оф docker image redis.

Запуская его так:

```
sudo docker run -it --name redis --network redis -p 6379:6379 -v /data/redis:/data redis
```

Если запускать redis-cli через докер образ в соседнем терминале, то все сохраняется, но только до пересборки контейнера.

Из кода пытаюсь подключиться по адресу 127.0.0.1:6379,  к базе.  Ошибок никаких нет, но данных тоже нет.

Что делаю не так? Как запускать контейнер, чтобы все данные были на месте в /data/redis как я и указал в ключе -v?

Comment: Если почитать [документацию](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis), она предлагает для сохранения данных добавить опцию `--save`, а в показанной вами команде такого нет, что сразу очень подозрительно

Comment: @andreymal Доку почитал, ключ save не помог. Данные все ещё не доходят до редиса. Та скорее всего там с хостом:портом проблема.